# Sails.js: Production env + sails-mysql - database tables not created upon lift

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

In production mode, when lifting a Sails application, the database tables are not created upon lift, while in dev mode, they are. Right now, when deploying, I'm running in dev mode once first so that the tables can be created and then running in prod mode. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No; this is by design.  In the production environment, Sails does not do any migration to ensure that data isn't corrupted or lost when lifting.

From the Sails [deployment guide](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Deployment?q=overview):

> Sails sets all your models to `migrate:safe` when run in production, which means no auto-migrations are run on starting up the app. You can set your database up the following way: Create the database on
>   the server and then run your sails app with `migrate:alter` locally, but
>   configured to use the production server as your db. This will
>   automatically set things up. In case you can't connect to the server
>   remotely, you'll simply dump your local schema and import it into the
>   database server.

Comment: Isn't it safe to create the table if it doesn't exist? I'm also having this problem and have no idea how to create all the tables now.